# Php error on ajax call script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

Well For Start I Want To Tank You All For The Help

The Script now it create a table but send empty info
so i have try to do like this:
http://mediaads.eu/villageop/back/savepoints.php?user_id=abcdefghijklm

Now The script wen i call it give me this error:

So I Have Edit The Script code to clean it 
 so now my code is:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "publiadd_publix";
$password = "1a3g7893fsh";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=publiadd_registervillageop", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}


if(isset($_GET['user_id'])){
     //$user_id = intval($_GET['user_id']);
     //Lightly sanitize the GET's to prevent SQL injections and possible XSS attacks

    try {
      $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=publiadd_registervillageop", $username, $password);

      $user_id = @$_GET['user_id'];  
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES ('".$_POST["user_id"]."')";
      if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
         echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
      }
      else{
         echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
      }    
      $dbh = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
?>

$sql->execute(array($user_Id));


     if($sql){         
          //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
          echo 'Your ID was saved. Congrats!';              
     }else{         
          //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
          echo 'There was a problem saving your points. Please try again later.';              
     }         
}else{
     echo 'Your id wasnt passed in the request.';
}

// close MySQL connection 
$conn = null;
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WTF does the `ruby-on-rails` tag in your question?

Comment: Please edit your tags & question to be more readable

Comment: Search array key **user_id** and print to check is the var really holds any value. Then Try to Insert into Table

Comment: Why you are setting the database connection twice? After first try/catch block, you can use it globally anywhere in your php file. Also, you are using PDO so you don't need to close the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using in your forms is GET so use `$_GET` not `$_POST` as it goes in your `if` condition. So replace `$_POST` with `$_GET` and second error is your table name it is `users` table not `publiadd_registervillageop` so your sql query looks like,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES ('".$_GET["user_id"]."')";
```

Comment: Tanks for The Help The Script now make a table but send empty data

Comment: Which error ? Did you change `$_POST` to `$_GET`, and make sure that you have `?user_id=1` in your calling URL

Comment: yes i have change the post to get and change the insert into

Comment: Tanks For Help Me To Solve This

Comment: i have clean a bit the code i don´t have understand which one i need to remove?

Comment: I think you should ask another question if the problem is new.

Comment: Ok I do tanks for the replay

Comment: well i am on the limit of questions

Comment: Try `$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES ('".$user_id."')";`